# How to use Animated GIF with TImage component?

Tags: c++, c++builder

In Delphi, the `Timage` component can play an animated GIF image:

```
(Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;
```

I convert this code to C++ equivalent:

```
((TGIFImage)Image1->Picture->Graphic)->Animate = true;
```

But I get an error:

```
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.cpp(60): no matching conversion for C-style cast from 'Vcl::Graphics::TGraphic *' to 'Vcl::Imaging::Gifimg::TGIFImage'
  Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.hpp(937): candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
```

What's the problem?

Comment: `Image1->Picture->Graphic` is a *pointer*. The type `TGIFImage` is *not* a pointer.

Comment: On another note, whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast (like you do) in C++, take that as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong. For a downcast use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` instead.

Comment: Thanks to Some : 
((TGIFImage*)Image1->Picture->Graphic)->Animate = true;
 Pointer solve the problem.

Comment: Use `static_cast` with the *right* type (`TGIFImage*`), and if `TGIFImage` inherits from `Vcl::Graphics::TGraphic` it should work fine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "*if `TGIFImage` inherits from `TGraphic`*" - [it does](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.TGIFImage).

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `*` in your type-cast:

```
((TGIFImage*)Image1->Picture->Graphic)->Animate = true;
           ^
```

And then, consider using a C++-style cast instead of a C-style cast:

```
static_cast<TGIFImage*>(Image1->Picture->Graphic)->Animate = true;
```